# Angular unit test test component method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

I try to test a component method. But I cannot invoke it.

[image]

```html
<!-- try to test addOrEditUser function -->
<table class="list" *ngIf="tableBody.length !== 0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let column of tableHeader">{{column.title}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr [ngClass]="checkClickability(row)" *ngFor="let row of tableBody" (click)="addOrEditUser(row)">
          <td class="inline" *ngFor="let d of row.slice(0, row.length - 1)">{{d}}</td>
          <td class="inline"><i class="fa fa-check" *ngIf="row[row.length - 1]"></i></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
// component
  public addOrEditUser(row: any[]): void {
    const isMember: boolean = row[row.length - 1];
    const profileId: string = row[0];

    // Do nothing if they are already a member
    if (isMember)
      return;
```

```js
// component.spec.ts
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(QuickSearchPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.createUserAttributes = attributeArray;
    component.existingUserAttributes = attributeArray;
    component.tableBody = tableBody;
    groupMembersService = TestBed.get(GroupMembersService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should do nothing if row data is member', () => {
    spyOn(groupMembersService, 'addMembers');
    const tr: DebugElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.search-page-table > table > tbody > tr'));
    tr[0].triggerEventHandler('click', null);  // 1. method 1, try to invoke it by triggerEventHandler
    component.addOrEditUser(tableBody[0]);     // 2. method 2, try to invoke it 
    expect(groupMembersService.addMembers).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I try to invoke the component.addOrEditUser by two ways, click the element and directly call it. But none of them are working. Anyone know something about it?

Comment: Hey, what test case is failing please?

Comment: I have a tableBody constant variable assigned.
```js
  const tableBody = [
    ['1', 'terry', 'tu', true],
    ['1', 'terry', 'tu', true],
    ['1', 'terry', 'tu', true],
  ];
```

Comment: Just cannot invoke component.addOrEditUser(row: any[]) method. I need to invoke it and expect(someService.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled() inside it.

Comment: Thanks man, i'm taking a look now.

Comment: Remove this and let me know what happens: `tr[0].triggerEventHandler('click', null); `

Comment: I try, but still the same. Cannot invoke it by `component.addOrEditUser(tableBody[0]);`. I add `snapshot` in the description above.

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the error?

Comment: Error is this `expect(groupMembersService.addMembers).toHaveBeenCalled();` failed. Which called inside component.addOrEditUser()

Comment: It can mean that you called another method. e.g. you have another GroupMembersService instance. Anyway you can check if `groupMembersService.addMembers` is really executed through debugging the process